# Constraining Eager Loads returning all items - correct relations data for matching query but also all other items as null in relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a search variable that I pass to return all items whose name matches the search variable. However instead of only returning the items that match it also return all other items with the relation as null. Ideally I'd like to only return the items that match my query.

In the example below, say I have 20 items with an items whose name is 'exampleName'. My query returns all twenty items. The items that match my query will contain the correct relations data as so:

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
        "author" => App\Models\User {#1447 ▼
        ...
        #attributes: array:9 [▼
            "id" => 2
            "name" => "exampleName"
            "surname" => "SurnameExample"
            "email" => "example@mail.com"
            "email_verified_at" => "2021-10-27 16:51:29"
            "password" => ""
            "remember_token" => null
            "created_at" => "2021-10-27 15:47:27"
            "updated_at" => "2021-11-01 15:32:28"
          ]
```

And all others items will show:

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
        "author" => null
      ]
```

I'm using livewire btw, this is my controller:

```
class PosterData extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public $search = 'exampleName';

    public function render()
    {   
        $search = $this->search;

        $posters = Poster::with(['author' => function ($query) use($search) {
             $query->where('name', 'like', '%'. $search . '%');
        }])->get();
            
        dd($posters);

        $posters->paginate(10);
        return view('livewire.poster-data', [
            'posters' => $posters,
        ]);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: you are looking for `whereHas` ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence ... you can apply that same closure to the `with` and `whereHas` if needed

Comment: Yup, that works. Thank you.